# Can lasers really show microbes in water?

Tags: optics, laser, geometric-optics, home-experiment

[image: experiment observation]

**I used a 532 nm green laser and passed its beam through a water droplet. Can you explain me are these really microbes and if they are then how a laser is able to do so?**

Comment: It looks more like inhomogeneities in the laser speckle to me.

Comment: Adding some more details about the picture would be helpful. For example, what was the laser-droplet distance? And what about the picture? Is it the image of the light arriving on a screen? Is there any lense?

Comment: Indeed, in the current state of the question, it's impossible for us to be sure what is causing these patterns. But @Miyase is right, it resembles inhomogeneities in the laser speckle amplified by refracting through the drop. However, I can see why you think they look like microbes. More information would paint us a clearer picture